# Pyarrow basic auth: How to prevent `Stream is closed`?

Tags: windows, stream, pyarrow

I am new to Arrow Flight and pyarrow (v=6.0.1), and am trying to implement basic auth but I am always getting an error:

```
OSError: Stream is closed
```

I have created a minimal reproducing sample, by running the following two files sequentially (representing server and client respectively):

```py
from typing import Dict, Union
from pyarrow.lib import tobytes
from pyarrow.flight import BasicAuth, FlightUnauthenticatedError, ServerAuthHandler, FlightServerBase
from pyarrow._flight import ServerAuthSender, ServerAuthReader


class ServerBasicAuthHandler(ServerAuthHandler):
    def __init__(self, creds: Dict[str, str]):
        self.creds = {user.encode(): pw.encode() for user, pw in creds.items()}

    def authenticate(self, outgoing: ServerAuthSender, incoming: ServerAuthReader):
        buf = incoming.read()  # this line raises "OSError: Stream is closed"
        auth = BasicAuth.deserialize(buf)
        if auth.username not in self.creds:
            raise FlightUnauthenticatedError("unknown user")
        if self.creds[auth.username] != auth.password:
            raise FlightUnauthenticatedError("wrong password")
        outgoing.write(tobytes(auth.username))

    def is_valid(self, token: bytes) -> Union[bytes, str]:
        if not token:
            raise FlightUnauthenticatedError("no basic auth provided")
        if token not in self.creds:
            raise FlightUnauthenticatedError("unknown user")
        return token

service = FlightServerBase(
    location=f"grpc://[::]:50051",
    auth_handler=ServerBasicAuthHandler({"user": "pw"}),
)

service.serve()
```

```py
from pyarrow.flight import FlightClient

client = FlightClient(location=f"grpc://localhost:50051")
client.authenticate_basic_token("user", "pw")
```

I basically copied the `ServerAuthHandler` implementation from [their tests](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/tests/test_flight.py), so it is proven to work. However, I can't get it to work.

The error message `Stream is closed` hard to debug. I don't know where it comes from and I can't trace it to anywhere within the pyarrow implementation (neither Pythonside nor C++ side). I can't see where it comes from.

Any help or hints on how to prevent this error would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I've tried to turn my answer here into a documentation page for Arrow, if you would like a fuller example: https://github.com/apache/arrow-cookbook/pull/123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the OP is mixing up two authentication implementations (which is indeed confusing). The "BasicAuth" object isn't actual HTTP basic authentication that the `authenticate_basic_token` method implements; this is because contributors have implemented a variety of authentication methods over the years. The actual test is as follows:

```py
header_auth_server_middleware_factory = HeaderAuthServerMiddlewareFactory()
no_op_auth_handler = NoopAuthHandler()


def test_authenticate_basic_token():
    """Test authenticate_basic_token with bearer token and auth headers."""
    with HeaderAuthFlightServer(auth_handler=no_op_auth_handler, middleware={
        "auth": HeaderAuthServerMiddlewareFactory()
    }) as server:
        client = FlightClient(('localhost', server.port))
        token_pair = client.authenticate_basic_token(b'test', b'password')
        assert token_pair[0] == b'authorization'
        assert token_pair[1] == b'Bearer token1234'
```

i.e. we're not using `authenticate` but rather a "middleware" to do the implementation. A full example looks as follows:

```py
import base64
import pyarrow.flight as flight

class BasicAuthServerMiddlewareFactory(flight.ServerMiddlewareFactory):
    def __init__(self, creds):
        self.creds = creds

    def start_call(self, info, headers):
        token = None
        for header in headers:
            if header.lower() == "authorization":
                token = headers[header]
                break

        if not token:
            raise flight.FlightUnauthenticatedError("No credentials supplied")

        values = token[0].split(' ', 1)
        if values[0] == 'Basic':
            decoded = base64.b64decode(values[1])
            pair = decoded.decode("utf-8").split(':')
            if pair[0] not in self.creds:
                raise flight.FlightUnauthenticatedError("No credentials supplied")
            if pair[1] != self.creds[pair[0]]:
                raise flight.FlightUnauthenticatedError("No credentials supplied")
            return BasicAuthServerMiddleware("BearerTokenValue")

        raise flight.FlightUnauthenticatedError("No credentials supplied")


class BasicAuthServerMiddleware(flight.ServerMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def sending_headers(self):
        return {'authorization': f'Bearer {self.token}'}


class NoOpAuthHandler(flight.ServerAuthHandler):
    def authenticate(self, outgoing, incoming):
        pass

    def is_valid(self, token):
        return ""


with flight.FlightServerBase(auth_handler=NoOpAuthHandler(), middleware={
    "basic": BasicAuthServerMiddlewareFactory({"test": "password"})
}) as server:
    client = flight.connect(('localhost', server.port))
    token_pair = client.authenticate_basic_token(b'test', b'password')
    print(token_pair)
    assert token_pair[0] == b'authorization'
    assert token_pair[1] == b'Bearer BearerTokenValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply due to this not being supported on Windows.

On closer inspection, the test that "proves it work" is being skipped in Windows. The comment refers to [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10013). That issue has been fixed though (ostensibly); not anything as to why it wouldn't work with `Stream is closed`.